# Please can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong running this Ruby script from IRB

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby and programing in general. I am trying to execute a simple ruby command from a ruby file from irb.

I have created a file sports.rb . it contains some hashes and a line of command to puts tennis as seen below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNBQ0.png)
But When I tried to execute the script I get the image below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlNWF.png)
According to the written command, I am suppose to get "long hours" when I run the script but its not happening. Can anyone please tell me what I

Comment: Post code, not pictures of code

Comment: 1. "please" should come right before the verb "tell". 2. The auxiliary verb "am" should not be inverted in embedded interrogatives. 3. The entire interrogative should end with a question mark. So, it should be: *Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong ...?*

Answer (score 1):

1) `Sports` with an uppercase defines a class or module, use `sports` for variables.
2) you opened irb and entered a string, you didn’t try and require the file or run it. I recommend you DONT open irb and instead run `ruby sports.rb` from the directory